# Iptables service reload or restart should restart another service, like Docker

Tags: iptables, docker, hook

I know there is a way, I just don't remind how to. I need to have the IPTables restart the Docker service when I reload, restart the iptables.

I am pretty sure there is a HOOK way to that with systemctl. Can someone light my way please ?

Regards,

Comment: Which linux distro?

Comment: RedHat Enterprise 7

Comment: Could I use the EXEC in IPtables like this ? : Exec=systemctl restart docker.service